# How do I remove myself from Facebook chat group?

Tags: facebook

My friend added me into his group and I want to quit it. Facebook doesn't ask any confirmation for adding me into that group. How do I quit it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **How do I leave a chat with multiple friends?**
>
> To stop receiving messages in a chat with multiple friends, open the actions menu in the top right corner of the chat window and select Leave Conversation.

From [here](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=213893238652556).

[image]

Comment: this will work even if they keep on sending messages to the chat group?

Comment: Based on my experience, yes.

Comment: See the screenshot I added to my initial answer.

Answer (score 2):

To remove yourself from a conversation with more than one friend:

1. Go to the conversation
2. Click Actions menu
3. Select Leave Conversation...

The other people in the conversation will be notified that you left and you will no longer receive messages from the conversation.

Keep in mind that you can only unsubscribe from group conversations. You won't be able to leave a one-on-one conversation. To prevent someone from starting a message thread with you, you can unfriend or block them.